# Another MySQL syntax error using INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

MySQL is returning a syntax error for this query (via PHP):

```
INSERT INTO links (link, name, desc, category) 
VALUES ('www.contoso.com', 'Contoso', 'My Website', 'Vanity')
```

> ERROR:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, category) VALUES ('www.contoso.com', 'Contoso', 'My Website', 'Vani' at line 1

I see nothing wrong with it. What gives?

Comment: As a general rule don't use reserved words for table or column names. It saves a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DESC is a MySQL reserved word... if you want to use it as a column name you must enclose it in backticks

The actual error message after the word "near" gives an indication of exactly where in your SQL statement the parser believes the error to be... in this case, at the word "desc". That can often be a good guide to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: In my noobness I didn't know it was a reserved word. Thanks!

Comment: I had tried ticking all the column names at one time and it didn't work. I changed it to "description" instead, and it worked.

Comment: @user513905 - make sure you used backticks (`) rather than single quotes (')

Comment: Wow, that would be the difference. I didn't pay attention to that little detail.

Answer (score 2):

`desc` is a [MySQL reserved keyword.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) It must be enclosed in backquotes as

```
INSERT INTO links (link, name, `desc`, category) VALUES ('www.datavirtue.com', 'Data Virtue', 'My Website', 'Vanity')
```

Answer (score 1):

"desc" is a reserved word. Use "description"

Answer (score 0):

DESC is a reserved word and must be escaped with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO links 
    (link, name, `desc`, category) 
    VALUES 
    ('www.datavirtue.com', 'Data Virtue', 'My Website', 'Vanity')
```